# Correctly grouping by and aggregating in order to avoid the random effects problem

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, pandas-groupby

I'm working with the Movielens 100k dataset (it has information about the movies - genre and the users - gender, age, etc.) that looks something like this:

```
  item_id              title release_date  video_release_date  \
0        1   Toy Story (1995)  01-Jan-1995                 NaN   
1        4  Get Shorty (1995)  01-Jan-1995                 NaN  

  Adventure  Animation  Childrens  ...  Thriller  War  Western  user_id  \
0          0          1          1  ...         0    0        0      308   
1          0          0          0  ...         0    0        0      308   

   rating  timestamp  age  gender  occupation  zip_code  
0       4  887736532   60       M     retired     95076  
1       5  887737890   60       M     retired     95076
```

I would like to compare the average rating score of the two genders (Male and Female) for each movie genre. However, it's not just enough to calculate the mean rating of all female vs all male users, as the male users are much more than the female ones. For that matter I have to somehow take care of that problem that I read about called random effects model.

I was thinking by somehow correctly grouping or applying aggregation in order to calculate the mean rating score that each user has given for each movie of that genre.

Code until now but it does not correctly capture and take care of the problem:

```
males = data.query("gender == ['M']")
male_movie_genre = males.iloc[:, 6:24]

movie_genre_labels = ['Action', 'Adventure' , 'Animation' , 'Childrens' , 'Comedy' , 'Crime' , 'Documentary' , 'Drama' , 'Fantasy' , 'Film-Noir' , 'Horror' , 'Musical' , 'Mystery' , 'Romance' , 'Sci-Fi' , 'Thriller' , 'War' , 'Western']
males['genre'] = pd.Series(male_movie_genre[labels].columns[np.where(male_movie_genre[labels]!=0)[1]])

avg_rating_per_genre_male_users = males.groupby(['user_id', 'genre'])['rating'].mean().reset_index()

mean_rating_values_male_users = avg_rating_per_genre_male_users.groupby(['genre'])['rating'].mean()
```

Or is there a better way to do this statistically correct?

Thank you very much in advance!